# Can't display Google Map in my Android apps

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps, phonegap

I have simple apps, apps will show a map. I build with Cordova. I have success to get my location, but not success to display map.

Here is my code :

```
<script>
        function onDeviceReady() {

        var options = { frequency: 3000 }; //THIS I SPECIFY INTERVAL TIME TO SEND POSITIONS
            var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, { timeout: 3000 });
            }


        function onSuccess(position) //IF SUCCESS
        {

        var element = document.getElementById('location_note');
        var lat=position.coords.latitude;
        var lang=position.coords.longitude;

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lang);

        var mapOptions={center : new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lang),zoom :4,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

        $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+position.coords.latitude+','+position.coords.longitude+'&sensor=false', function(data) {
        alamats = data.results[0];//aRRAy to capture address details
        al=alamats.formatted_address; //variable to capture Address
        });


        element.innerHTML="";//APPEND ADDRESS INFO 
         element.innerHTML = '<center><p><font color="#FFFFFF" face="arial" size="4"> ' + al + '</font><br />' + '</p></center>'; //Success to Display My Address

            }

            function onError(error) {
              alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
            }  
    </script>
    <body>
     <div id="my_location">Address Info here</div>
     <div id="map_canvas">PETA</div>
    </body>
```

I got the address info, but the map is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

Add a style to the map:

```
<style>
    #map_canvas {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

Also, as Google Maps doesn't require a device to work, you can test and debug it in the browser. Execute this from your app directory:

```
ionic serve -c -s
```

press F12 in the browser and edit it as you wish. And don't forget to monitor the `Console` tab to see any possible error (like the ones you have in the code you have posted, my_location -> location_note). Take a look at the [testing docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/testing.html).

In any case, I would simplify the app to the minimum expression, in order to try to make it to work and to avoid mistakes (remove geolocation code, hardcode center location, etc).

Take this plunker as example: https://plnkr.co/edit/gEm60LZwxS2tggceBKOf?p=preview, and the [google maps hello world example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#The_Hello_World_of_Google_Maps_v3).